# Flutter Driver: Test BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

how do I test BottomNavigationBarItems via **FlutterDriver**?

**FlutterDriver** allows accessing Widgets via **text**, **byValueKey**, **byTooltip** and **byType**.

But none of these methods work out for my App because of following reasons:

- **text**: The App is localized and I need to test the App in multiple languages.
- **byValueKey**: BottomNavigationBarItems do not have **key** properties.
- **byTooltip**: BottomNavigationBarItems do not have **toolTip** properties.
- **byType**: byType only returns the first match of the type and no list (needed because I have multiple tabs).

Thank you very much!

Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you have found answer for this question, but I am going to post a solution here which works for me. Basically, `BottomNavigationBar` has a `key` property which you need to use. Once Flutter Driver identifies this key, then you can tell driver to tap on any of its child items ie `BottomNavigationBarItem`.

My screen has 2 `bottomNavigationBarItems` as shown below and I defined key for their parent widget ie `BottomNavigationBar` as:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        key: Key('bottom'),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.green,),
            title: Text('First', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.cast, color: Colors.yellow,),
            title: Text('Second', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
          )
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

And I wrote a flutter driver test to tap on both items which worked perfectly.

```
test('bottomnavigationbar test', () async {
      await driver.waitFor(find.byValueKey('bottom'));
      await driver.tap(find.text('First'));
      print('clicked on first');
      await driver.tap(find.text('Second'));
      print('clicked on second too');
    });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works, but unfortunately not for me. My App is localized and therefore has different texts depending on your language.

Comment: @basedgod can't we use key on the Text widget? ``` BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon( Icons.settings),
        title: Text(
          'Settings',
          key: const Key('settings'),
        ),``` it seems to work for me.

Comment: Yeah, like bsr, putting the key on the Icon worked for me.

Comment: It seems that `flutter_driver` is no longer recommended way to go: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests/migration

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @bsr and @user12563357- you can use the **key** on Text widget:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        key: Key('bottom'),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            title: Text('First', key: Key('first'),)
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.cast),
            title: Text('Second', key: Key('second'),)
          )
        ],
      ),
```

and find the text to click on the bar item in test:

```
final firstItem = find.byValueKey('first');
await driver.tap(firstItem);
```

btw: you can also find BottomNavigationBarItem using **find.ancestor**

```
find.ancestor(of: firstItem, matching: find.byType("BottomNavigationBarItem"));
```

but you can't tap on it.

Comment: Would it work to put a key on Icon?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options - byIcon or with text by getting the localization from the context.

You can get the state of any kind of StatefulWidget.

```
final MyWidgetState state = tester.state(find.byType(MyWidget));
```

with this you can get the context and with that the current localizaion.

```
final l10n = AppLocalizations.of(state.context);

await tester.tap(find.text(l10n.youTitle));
```

One other option is to get the widget by Icon:

```
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.your_icon));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        key: Key(`bottom`),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.green,),
            title: InkWell(child:Text(`First`, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),key:Key(`First`)),)
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.cast, color: Colors.yellow,),
            title:  InkWell(child:Text(`Second`, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),key:Key(`Second`)),)
          )
        ],
      ),


test(`bottomnavigationbar test`, () async {
      await driver.waitFor(find.byValueKey(`bottom`));
      await driver.tap(find.byValueKey(`First`));
      print('clicked on first');
      await driver.tap(find.byValueKey(`Second`));
      print('clicked on second too');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please explain a the code and how/why it works. Just with code it's hard to understand the answer.

Comment: Add  "InkWell" widget as a title for BottomNavigationBarItem and add Text as a child for InkWell. Now you can have static english key for InkWell widget, which no need to change based on locale and after that using "driver.tap(find.byValueKey('key'))" api you can achieve that BottomNavigationBarItem ontap functionality.